# Wix repair : files are still held by service although it was stopped and deleted

Tags: wix, repair

Making Wix install for my service app I ran into such trouble - when I choose "repair" option, after install i am **prompted to restart** my pc. 
  Actually my test install contains only two files.Although there are attributes that make installer **stop the service** (and it actually stops and uninstall service due to log), files **are still busy with the service's process**. 
 What am I doing wrong? Is there any workarounds? How Can i get rid of restart prompting in this case?
here is the code of installer:

```
<Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="AGENTFOLD">
            <Component Id="WindowsAgent" Guid="*">
        <File Id="WinAgent" KeyPath="yes" Source="WindowsAgent.exe"/>
        <ServiceInstall Id='WindowsAgentInst' Name='WindowsAgent' DisplayName='WindowsAgent' Type='ownProcess' Account='LocalSystem' Start='auto' ErrorControl='normal'/>
        <ServiceControl Id="WindowsAgentControl" Name="WindowsAgent" Stop="both" Start="install" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp2" Guid="GUIDHERE">
        <File Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="mydll.dll" />
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
```

here is what log says:

> Info 1603. The file C:\Program Files(x86)\WindowsAgent\mydll.dll  is
>   being held in use.  Close that application and retry.
>
> MSI (s)  (88:78) [17:01:50:993]: Product: Setuptest. The file 
>   C:\Program Files  (x86)\WindowsAgent\mydll.dll  is being used by the
>   following process: Name: WindowsAgent , Id
>    3384.
>
> Info 1603. The file C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\WindowsAgent\WindowsAgent.exe is being held in use.  Close that 
>   application and retry.
>
> MSI (s) (88:78) [17:01:51:182]: Product: Setuptest. The file
>   C:\Program Files(x86)\WindowsAgent\WindowsAgent.exe is being used by
>   the following process: Name: WindowsAgent , Id 3384.

Note that if I stop service manually before repair, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the common reasons for this are:

1. The Service may be "stopped" in the sense that the service protocol has been completed and the process is no longer running as a service, but the process is still running and hasn't terminated. Serviced stopped != Process terminated. So it's timing thing, and if there is a lot going on it may take a while for the process to go away and release the Dlls. That doesn't happen when you shut down the service manually because nobody cares if the process takes a while to shut down. The install/uninstall is a race between the process shutting down and Windows wanting to get rid of the in-use Dlls. The service may be misbehaving in some way, can't rule that out.
2. Something has a handle open to the service or the process. That seems unlikely in your case, but if there are apps on the system or in the install (like a custom action) that have opened service handles or process handles then they can't be fully terminated.

Comment: Thanks for reply.It is very helpful ! So i think i should add custom action after service stop to check the process state and to wait till it terminates.

Comment: Maybe, or if you own the service code perhaps make an event log entry when the service stops being a service and as the very last thing the process does when it exits. That might indicate a timing race if you compare it with the MSI log, and inspecting the service code might be useful anyway to see what it does affter it stops being a service. A lot of cleanup code?